# Unable to enocde Url using wiremock

Tags: mocking

I have following in mapping folder:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "PUT",
        "url": "/aayush&]"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

When i am hitting `http://localhost/aayush&]`

I am getting illegal argument expection.

Comment: Guessing you mean Exception?

Comment: Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 8: /aayush&]
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3067)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3025)
 at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:577)
 at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:839)
 ... 24 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Java's URI class takes a stricter view of what's valid than many other libraries.

There's already one open issue about this on Github, so it's on my to-do list.

In the meantime if you can, I'd suggest escaping the ] character.